# Kendo-grid Infinite scrolling feature not working in js/cshtml(.NET)

Tags: c#, vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo-grid infinite scrolling feature is not working. Below is the code, I will explain some approaches I took

```
<div id="gridContainer2" class="width-800">
                        <kendo-datasource ref="testDS"
                                          :transport-read="getResponses"
                                          :page-size="formResponseSearchQuery.PageSize"
                                          :server-paging="true"
                                          :server-sorting="true"
                                          :server-filtering="true"
                                          :schema-data="'ResultSet'"
                                          :schema-total="'TotalRows'"
                                          :schema-model-id="'FormResponseId'">
                        </kendo-datasource>
                        <kendo-grid ref="responseGrid"
                                    id="responseGrid"
                                    :data-source-ref="'testDS'"
                                    :height="500"
                                    :width="800"
                                    :scrollable-endless="true"
                                    :sortable="true"
                                    :server-sorting="true"
                                    :columns="responseGridColumns"
                                    :selectable="true"
                                    v-on:change="openResponseView">
                        </kendo-grid>
</div>
```

1. I made it work by using :pageable-page-size attribute, but that shouldn't be used there is this condition.
2. :scrollable-virtual="true" did not work
3. However referring: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/endless-scrolling-remote
   I tried to use

scrollable:
{
endless: true
},
which is not working.

Is the way being tried to use :scrollable-endless is right? Or Is there other right approach.

Comment: Can you clarify which one you are using? The title says `VueJs`, the documentation you linked `jQuery` and the tag `angular2`

Comment: We had the application migrated from angular to Vue, wanted to get input from who had idea of both angular & vue.  The documentation in general show what is the approach to make something infinitely scrollable. Logic is the same. I want to know if the syntax  I am using was right.

Comment: According to the documentation, you should have either a [`@scroll="scrollHandler"`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/scroll-modes/#toc-infinite-scrolling) or use [`:scrollable="'virtual'"`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/scroll-modes/#toc-virtual-scrolling) which has a page size as requirement. Why shouldn't pagegsize be used? It's just a value, how much rows you want to load at the end of the current loaded rows.

Comment: :scrollable="virtual" did not work. In the project, they have maintained a pattern not to use pagesize, that's the reason. You mentioned @scroll="scrollHandler", where to add that in my code & what does the function scrollHandler contain?